# Can I make ferrite paint? Will it shield my antenna from my roof?

Tags: antenna-theory, ferrite

I have a 3 element vertical Yagi mounted on a rotator, and in one direction the roof of the house gets pretty close and messes up the SWR a bit.

If i mash up a few type 43 material ferrite cores and mix them in some paint and paint the roof near my Yagi with that, will that make the roof 'invisible' to my Yagi?

Comment: Apparently, ferrite paint is a thing (Google *ferrite paint*). But how it is mixed -and with what- likely will affect its RF properties.

Comment: I'm also very confused why changing the electromagnetic properties of your roof to be more like a ferromagnetic metal surface would make your invisible to your yagi? I mean, this is not even a gross simplification: Metal close to any antenna changes the antenna. Non-conductive, non-magnetic material: usually not as much of a change. What do you mean with "invisible"?

Comment: @MarcusMüller i guess then the answer to my question is no :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. At best it will do nothing; if it did something, it would probably turn your roof from a relatively good reflector (which may mess with your SWR, and may distort your pattern, but the energy that doesn't go where you expected it at least goes somewhere) to a relatively *bad* reflector (which absorbs energy from your antenna and turns it into heat — ferrites are lossier than metals, and whatever you do to make it into "paint" will almost certainly increase that). What it won't do is make your wall RF-transparent.